# Create RPM from pre-built binary with no source code

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, fpm

I'm trying to create an `rpm` package for [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/downloads.html). I can download the Vault binary as a zip file from the website, but clueless about how to get that binary packed as an rpm. I tried `fpm` but I guess I can't use that for packaging pre-built binaries.

I know a directory tree has to be setup to create an rpm, but I don't know what to put in the files inside it, as all I have is a vault binary zipped. No sure about what to put in `SPEC` file either

I could create a `deb` for the same using `dhmake` followed by `debuild`, but not sure how to go about creating an rpm.

Any help? :sad_panda:

Answer (score 1):

FPM was the solution. Just that I couldn't figure out the right way to use it. So this is what I used:
Downloaded the `zip` file, extracted the binary file ($filename), then
`mkdir -p /install/vault; cp $filename /install/vault/`

````
fpm -s dir \
-t rpm \
--name vault \
--version 0.6.4 \
--url https://www.vaultproject.io \
-C /install/vault \
.```
````

FPM is awesome!

Answer (score -1):

It actually does not matter if you package binaries or compile it from source. Just learn how to package SW as RPM. Here is bunch of links to study: https://fedorahosted.org/copr/wiki/UserDocs#HowcanIpackagesoftwareasRPM